# Ability to deny answers

Tags: feature-request

Every now and then when I post a question somebody places an answer, but does not actually answer my question/solve the problem I am looking for and WPSE treats it as a legitimate answer and it affects the accept rating, which in turn affects the likely hood of me getting an answer on future questions.

I was wanting to propose the ability to have like a dash or a cross button that, without damage to the answerers rep, basically says "Cheers for the answer but it isn't what I am looking for and/or didn't solve the problem."

I believe this would be beneficial as new people across the question will be able to see that the question has not been answered and make an informed decision on whether or not they want to help, rather than assume that the question has been answered or is in correspondence.

Comment: I think your question is valid. Of course the people with moderator capabilities are not going to want to hear it, though.

Answer (score 9):

You already have tools in place for this:

1. Down voting
2. Leaving comments explaining *why* the answer is insufficient
3. Editing your original question to provide additional details to remove confusion
4. Offering a bounty on an unanswered question to get more attention

Comment: As a general rule I do all of those, bar the 4th, and even so my question still ends up in never-never land with no (legitimate) response.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine that someone comes around who asks a question. He has no coding knowledge, doesn't want to pay a dev (WPSE offers free solutions) but wants to have Google Docs rebuilt on WordPress.

Then imagine that someone drives by, tells him what would be necessary, links some basic stuff like auto saving revisions, WP_List_Tables, etc, but doesn't post the full code.

Now imagine the user denies this as legitimate answer. What would happen? Other users would be fooled by his accept rate and still trying to answer his on going questions. The result: frustration.

The SE network has a lot of secret tools built in to protected the *answering* community from trolls, knowledge vampires and else.

As @EAMann mentioned: You already got a lot of tools to deal with off-topic or wrong answers. If you're still not satisfied with the answers you got, then you'll have to take a look at your Qs:

1. "Are my Qs asked well?" » Post everything the people answering might need.
2. "Are my Qs well formatted?" » Use the editor to make them easy to read.
3. "Did I ask too much?" » Split it up and ask step by step.
4. "Are my Qs interesting?" » People use the site to extend their knowledge by answering, not repeating or doing jobs for others.

etc...

Comment: Exactly, tl;dr - The quality of the answer is directly related to the question.